# iOS: How can I generate coloured & rounded icons with alphabets based on cell item to use in a UITableView cell like in gmail app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to have a rounded & coloured image view, within a table cell. The image must be generated based on the item within that cell, using a certain logic (like having the first letter of sender's name in gmail app).

Is there a library that does this?

Comment: Try something like have square UIView with it's .layer.cornerRadius = height/2, with a UILabel centered in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating the image, you can make a custom view that has what you want.  Could be as simple as a `UILabel`:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)]
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
label.layer.borderRadius = label.frame.size.height / 2.0f;
```

Once you have this (and you could just use this, honestly...) you can covert this to an image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(label.frame.size);
label.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now you have a `UIImage` that you should cache & store somewhere so you can retrieve it without re-rendering it every time you need it.

To color the view, you can modify the above, or use image templating:

```
UIImage *templateImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

The images non-transparent pixels will be colored with the `tintColor`.  You'd have to modify the above to use `clearColor` for the text in this case.

Comment: I had to add label.layer.maskToBounds = YES and then it worked